# Sybase database password "recovery"

Tags: passwords, sybase, sqlanywhere, password-recovery

I have DBA authority to a sybase database on Windows.

I have a another user that I don't know the password for.

I regularly use an application that *does* know the password, and it uses the password to automatically login to the application. However, I can't find a way to find that password anywhere in the application or its dlls/files/registry/etc.

I obviously don't want to just change the password of the user, as the password in the application can't be updated (that i know of).

I want to be able to login to the database as this user.

Are there any logging settings for the database server that will log the password in plaintext? Or any other methods I can use to obtain the password (maybe via login_procedure)? **I'd also be okay with just obtaining the hash for the password(+salt).**

Comment: How is this related to software development, i.e. issues you are having with code?

Comment: "Are there any logging settings for the database server that will log the password in plaintext?" -- If there are, I wouldn't want to be a user on that server. Storing passwords in plaintext is generally a bad idea. (I won't say "always," because there's an exception to most rules... but yeah, pretty much always.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, good question, I've been attempting to find the database using misc SQL queries and procedures as well as debugging from via Visual Studio and Process Monitor. Also, once found, I'll be using this password within my own application in order to access the database. So, while I've been attempting to solve my problem with code myself, I do understand if you need to close this question as Off Topic.

Comment: @BrianS, I agree. Unfortunately I'm in one of those situations where getting the password in plaintext is desperately needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no SAP Sybase supported way to get the password in plaintext. You can view the hashed password by querying `master..syslogins.passwords` column.

A possible workaround would be to create a new user, and alias them to user in question inside the database.

`sp_addalias` is the command you would use to do something like that.

You can view the hashed password

Comment: I'm sure there is *a way*; I have a hard time believing sybase databases and servers are impenetrable. I could probably take a long time and figure out how to set up a fake sybase server, which should allow me to obtain the Connection String...but I don't know where to start in order to do this.

Comment: I'd also be okay with the password hash, btw.

Comment: `Select password from syslogins` returns `NULL` for all users.

Comment: Found it with `SELECT password from sys.sysuser`. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, you are using SQLAnywhere?  My answer is for Sybase ASE, sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry about that! I also just discovered that the specific algorithm used for SQL anywhere password hashes is unpublished. :-(. All I know now is that "0x01283d44932d9c08e1cddf11097c646c62386f9504692b08db345742f6224c92fdae140e01" is a SHA-256 hashed 12-character password (found this length information elsewhere) with padding and a unique salt. In other words: I'm still just a stuck as before. haha

Comment: @DavidMurdoch I can't imagine the hash would be of any real use to you. The database server obviously isn't impenetrable. You're logged into it as a DBA. But you're not able to *impersonate* the other user without knowing the password. And that password won't be in plaintext anywhere. Who in their right mind would hardcode a password into an application?

Comment: QuickBooks Desktop

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the plaintext password as it's not logged anywhere and we don't store it. What's stored in the ISYSUSER system table is the SHA-256 *hash* of the password, and so it is not possible to get the password from it. (And it's not the hash of just the password - it includes a random salt.)

However, if you have DBA authority, you can do anything in the database anyway. If you *need* to be connected as that particular user, you can connect as the user with DBA authority and then use the [SETUSER](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbreference/setuser-statement.html%2ad5e67953) statement.

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: Right, I figured it had a salt, though I'm not sure how long or where in the hash it is stored. My guess is that the first byte (0x01) isn't  important, the next 72 contain the hash and the salt, with 64 of these characters representing the hash, leaving an 8 character (4 byte hex) salt. I tried over 600000 methods of hashing to try to reproduce to no avail, haha.

Comment: Some background information: I've got about 400 files that all have a user named `auto_user` all with the same (unknown) password (at least I *think* it is the same for each). This user and password was created by a 3rd party application. While I *can* get DBA access on all of these files, it is a painstaking process, as the DBA username and password is different on each - and I don't want to have to maintain this (sensitive) information.

Comment: As far as it not being possible to get the password from the hash ... I'm actually okay with running a high-powered machine or 10 for a couple of weeks in attempt to brute force it. So if I COULD get the has algo, that would actually help a lot (obviously I know you aren't going to publish it, I just wanted to explain my intentions).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.thegrideon.com/qb-internals-sql2.html

As highlighted several times in the previous parts QuickBooks company files are SQL Anywhere database files, but QB credentials are not used for SQL Anywhere directly. User name is converted to Hex string and password is calculated based on QB password and converted to hex string as well.

Default pair "Admin" with empty password converted into SQL Anywhere:
UID=41646d696e
PWD=064e7afebcfbae000b22c7c85e5560f89a2a028000
PWD format for QuickBooks 2018 & 2019 (SQL Anywhere 17) is different:
PWD=074c99f858df3c75f8add53fe5b3413e25cb3c2f98ec3545ae8dbe5bebda83d9fa00

SQL Anywhere UID & PWD Calculator is part of QuickBooks Forensics functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to decompile the application program and look for the password. I don't know who in their right mind would hard code a password into program code, but it kind of sounds like that is what happened here? Alternatively, if it is an internally-developed app, do you have access to the source code?

If that *is* what happened, and you have the ability to recompile the app, use the keyring (Mac, Linux) or DPAPI (Windows) to securely (as much as possible) store an encrypted instance of the password outside the application code. You'll be able to change it, and some random person who manages to hack in and get access to the source code or binary won't be able to inspect the program like I'm suggesting you try.

I also realize this is an old post and you've either solved the problem or moved on by now.  ;-)

Comment: The application is QuickBooks Desktop, and it gains access to the underlying SQL Anywhere server without the users password somehow. We haven't solved the problem, just worked around it.

Comment: Oohhh, QuickBooks. My condolences.    ;-)

Comment: I wonder if they're just doing a logon mapping from something like the Windows Everyone group to DBA and using integrated authentication? Just musing out loud.